# How to add a column to sql result from other row in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

For example I have a table:

```
num | value | info
1   | a     | test2
2   | a     | test1
1   | b     | specialinfo
3   | a     | test3
```

And I have a query

```
select * 
from t 
where value='a'
```

It will result

```
1 a test2
2 a test1
3 a test3
```

But I want to add `info` for value `b` as not a new row but as an additional column, so it will be like:

```
1 a test2 specialinfo
2 a test1 null
3 a test3 null
```

so value `specialinfo` goes as additional column and not as additional row.

For this case `select * from t where value IN ('a','b')` will not work

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the details in a separate column one way to do this would be to join on the table multiple times to get the result:

```
select t1.num, t1.value, t1.info, t2.info as t2_info
from yt t1
left join yt t2
  on t1.num = t2.num
  and t1.value <> t2.value
where t1.value = 'a';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78a55/5)